# Can't Focus on ContentEditable Table Cell in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using the following to change the value of a contenteditable table cell and then focus on it

```
$("#click").click(function(){
        $("#location").text("me");
        $("#location").focus();
        return false;
});
```

The above works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE.  In Internet Explorer, the text method is processed, but the focus method does not work.  Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6QQq4/2/).  I've tried using a [combination](http://jsfiddle.net/6QQq4/3/) of setTimeout with the jQuery method and using [vanilla JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/6QQq4/4/) to get the DOM element.  Unfortunately, none of these methods force IE to focus on the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I transferred the HTML attributes from the TD to the inner DIV.

```
<td id = 'location' contenteditable = 'true' width = '250px'>
    <div contenteditable = 'true'>
```

became

```
<td>
    <div contenteditable = 'true' width = '250px' id = 'location'>
```

Solved the problem.  Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6QQq4/8/)

Comment: If cell size is not fixed, add `display:inline-block; width:100%;height:100%;` to div's style.